# Is there a way to recognize '\n' while using right shift on reading text

Tags: c++, text, format, operator-keyword

heres my text file format

Lenihan retired in 1995 as an associate professor of sociology

at John Jay College of Criminal Justice. He had joined the faculty

in 1980, after earlier stints as a researcher at Columbia

and here's my code

```
ifstream  afile("sometext.txt");
string line;
while (afile >> line) {
    cout<< line <<" "
    }
afile.close();
```

and it prints without any new line

is it possible to print new line only using right shift on string?

Comment: No, `'\n'` counts as a whitespace character and is consumed seamlessly. Alternatively you can read whole lines with `std::getline()`.

Comment: You appeared to be confused about `<<`. For a start, were it a bit-shift operator, it would be *left* shift, not right. But that's irrelevant, since it's *not* a bit-shift operator in this context, it is instead an insertion operator.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it but using a character instead of string, use peek() and scan the input buffer whether it contains '\n' or not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main()
{

    std::ifstream  afile("sometext.txt");
    std::string line;
    char c;

    while ( !afile.eof())
    {
        afile >> c;
        if('\n' == afile.peek())
        {
            c = '\n';
            line += c;
        }
        else
            line += c;

    }

    std::cout << line << std::endl;

    afile.close();

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```